# Select Rows based on constraints across multiple rows

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

## Question:

I am using closure tables to track user file permissions, and, after a `JOIN`, this results in multiple `read` booleans across multiple rows. I want to only select a row, if all of the joined rows are readable. Using `UNION` obviously does not achieve this.

## Details:

**Folders table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS folders
(
   id                    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   path                  VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
   r                     BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)engine=innodb;
```

**Files table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files
(
   id                    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   parent_folder_id      INT NOT NULL ,
   path                  VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
   r                     BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
   FOREIGN KEY ( parent_folder_id ) REFERENCES folders ( id ),
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)engine=innodb;
```

**Folder-Parent Folder closure table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parent_folders
(
   id                INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   folder_id         INT NOT NULL,
   parent_folder_id  INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY ( folder_id ) REFERENCES folders ( id ),
   FOREIGN KEY ( parent_folder_id ) REFERENCES folders ( id ),
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
)engine=innodb;
```

Now, if I want to get all the readable files (ignoring for the moment that I have omitted users entirely), I would start out like so

```
SELECT 
    F.id, F.path, F.r, P.parent_folder_id, D.path, D.r
FROM
    files AS F 
    LEFT JOIN parent_folders AS P 
        ON F.parent_folder_id = P.folder_id 
    LEFT JOIN folders AS D  
        ON P.parent_folder_id = D.id;
```

This will display a table of every file id, path and read permissions, as accessible from each of its parent folders like so

```
id   path                  r     id  path          r
......
0   /home/joe/foo/bar.txt  True  1   /home/joe/foo True
1   /home/joe/foo/bar.txt  True  2   /home/joe     True
1   /home/joe/foo/bar.txt  True  3   /home         True
1   /home/joe/foo/bar.txt  True  4   /             True
2   /home/jim/foo/bar.txt  True  5   /home/jim/foo True
2   /home/jim/foo/bar.txt  True  6   /home/jim     False
2   /home/jim/foo/bar.txt  True  7   /home         True
2   /home/jim/foo/bar.txt  True  8   /             True
....
```

In this case, I would like to `SELECT` `/home/joe/foo/bar.txt` because every parent folder leading down to it is readable, but I would not want to `SELECT` `/home/jim/foo/bar.txt` because one of its parent folders is not readable.

**EDIT:** Alternatively, I could rephrase the question like so: "Can I `AND` the values of one column across multiple rows?"

Comment: @Sarfraz I find if I spend an extra 15 minutes formatting, my question gets 500% more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with non-standard SQL but this depends on your database vendor. For example, you might want to check hierarchical queries with the `CONNECT BY` clause in Oracle. There may be something similar for MySQL. However, I would suggest against such a solution for three reasons:

1. Vendor lock-in.
2. It is not clear how efficient those queries are, or how to optimize them.
3. The complexity increases very quickly if you want more rules like this (like inheritable user permissions for example).

Instead, I would suggest the following approach which I have used in several medium to large scale projects:

1. For the `r` field use three-state booleans (`TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NULL`), where `NULL` will stand for "inherit".
2. Add a new field `effective_r` for each file (and maybe for each folder). This will contain the result of applying all the inheritance rules and can only be `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Of course, you will have to calculate this field on every change of the hierarchy, but this is faster as updates are not that often and when they happen, they affect only a part of the hierarchy.
3. Define top-down propagation rules. In this case it is easy:

   ```
   parent effective_r       child r        child effective_r
   ---------------------    ------------   ---------------------
   <ROOT>                   NULL           TRUE
   <ROOT>                   TRUE           TRUE
   <ROOT>                   FALSE          FALSE
   TRUE                     NULL           TRUE
   FALSE                    NULL           FALSE
   TRUE|FALSE               TRUE           TRUE
   TRUE|FALSE               FALSE          FALSE
   ```

   The rules can be much more complicated and sophisticated for user permissions.

Comment: what if I ask the question like this: Can I `AND` the columns across multiple rows?

Comment: wrt your answer, I think you are updating ALL file permissions on any change. A single `chmod 0000 /home/joe` command, albeit very unlikely, would halt the entire system.

Comment: @puk, yes you can, but you have to resort to vendor specific extensions. For the reasons I explained, you should better not.

Answer (score 0):

Add a WHERE clause

```
WHERE D.r = TRUE
```

**EDIT**

Do improvements as you want

```
SELECT F.id, F.path, F.r, P.parent_folder_id, D.path, D.r
FROM files AS F
LEFT JOIN parent_folders AS P ON F.parent_folder_id = P.folder_id
LEFT JOIN folders AS D ON P.parent_folder_id = D.id
WHERE F.path NOT IN
    (SELECT A.path
     FROM files AS A
     LEFT JOIN parent_folders AS B ON A.parent_folder_id = B.folder_id
     LEFT JOIN folders AS C ON B.parent_folder_id = C.id
     WHERE C.r = FALSE)
```

Comment: I actually didn't try this, but I believe that works on a row by row bases, when what I want is to only `SELECT F.id` if all the `D.r` columns are all True.

Comment: What does this do? Shouldn't the last `TRUE` be `FALSE`, then that might work.

Comment: As I suspected this results in duplicates, is there any way to prevent this/fix this?

Comment: Apparently adding a `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM...` does the trick

Comment: I can't check the result without having data. It's up to you to do necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.path
from (
    SELECT 
        F.path, D.r
    FROM
        files AS F 
        LEFT JOIN parent_folders AS P 
            ON F.parent_folder_id = P.folder_id 
        LEFT JOIN folders AS D  
            ON P.parent_folder_id = D.id
) a
left join (
    SELECT 
        F.path, D.r
    FROM
        files AS F 
        LEFT JOIN parent_folders AS P 
            ON F.parent_folder_id = P.folder_id 
        LEFT JOIN folders AS D  
            ON P.parent_folder_id = D.id
) b on a.path = b.path and b.r = false
where b.r is null
group by path
```

Comment: Is this valid syntax? What are those trailing `a` and `b` letters, should there not be an `AS` statement?

Comment: I didn't test it but [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) says the `AS` keyword is optional.

Comment: I see now. ok I will test it out